# Connection fail to SQL Server using NodeJS mssql msnodesqlv8 from the server

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I wrote a little service in NodeJS which connects to SQL Server.

In my local machine, the connection is established successfully.
After putting my files in a remote machine, I get this error:

> ConnectionError: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not
>   found and no default driver specified

I use windows authentication but when the username didn't have permissions, I got a different error.

```
const mssql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");

const mypool = new mssql.ConnectionPool({
        driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
        server: myhost,
        database: mydb,
        port: 1443,
        options: {
            trustedConnection: true,
            enableArithAbort: true
        }
});

mypool.connect().then(pool => {
    console.log('Connected to MSSQL (DB: mydb)');
    return pool;
}).catch(err => console.log('Database Connection Failed! Bad Config: ', err))
```

Comment: you database is running on the same machine as your service ? can you connect to the database using a command ?

Comment: @Eitank database running on another machine. used telnet and I got an answer.

Comment: @EitanK I tried to use SQL Server Authentication from the machine I'm having problem with and it worked. I only have issues with Windows Authentication.

Comment: well, why do you need windows auth ?

Comment: @Eitank This is the requirement. I have to login using Windows authentication.

Comment: Is the database running on a windows server?

Comment: @Eitank Yes, the DB running on Windows server.

Comment: So you might have something bad in the config, contact your sys admin

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the connection pool as below,

```
const pool=new sql.ConnectionPool (config, function(err){
 if(err){
   console.log('Error while creating connection pool \n'+err);
 }
});
```